# CSS HTML - How to make the anchor pictures go to a specific spot

Tags: html, css

How do I make all my anchor links / images go to specific sides I want the teams one on top left I want store top right sponsors bottom left and about us bottom right I thought I did all the right code but they don't how up in those specific spots

If anyone can help it will be greatly appreciates

**CSS**

```css
.icon1.jpg {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      height: auto;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .icon2.jpg {
      position: relative;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      height: auto;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .icon4.jpg {
      position: relative;
      left: 0px;
      height: auto;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .icon3.jpg {
      position: relative;
      right: 0px;
      height: auto;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .DelUZens {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    body {
      background: url("icon6.jpg") repeat;
    }
    #banner {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 175px;
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
 <html>
    <head>
      <title>DelUZens</title>
      <link href="main.css" rel="stlesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#000">
        <div z-index:1;>
          <p>
            <a href="teams.html" target="_blank">
              <img src="icon1.jpg" style='width:50%;' border="0" alt="Null" class="top" z-index:2>
            </a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a href="store.html" target="_blank">
              <img src="icon2.jpg" style='width:50%;' border="0" alt="Null" class="right" z-index:3>

            </a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a href="sponsors.html" target="_blank">
              <img src="icon4.jpg" style='width:50%;' border="0" alt="Null" class="left" z-index:4>
            </a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a href="aboutus.html" target="_blank">
              <img src="icon3.jpg" style='width:50%;' border="0" alt="Null" class="bottom" z-index:5>
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="myDiv" style="position:absolute; top:230px; left:591px; right: 591px; bottom: 230px;  width:0px; height:0px; z-index:8;">
          <img src="icon5.png" class="DelUZens">
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try to set bottom: 0 to elements you want to show up at the bottom

Comment: @markoffden I tried that it didn't work thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

if (myDiv) in a nother page use this

```
            <a href="teams.html#myDiv" target="_blank">
              <img src="icon1.jpg" style='width:50%;' border="0" alt="Null" class="top" z-index:2>
            </a>
```

if (myDiv) in the same page use this

```
 <a href="#myDiv" target="_blank">
 <img src="icon1.jpg" style='width:50%;' border="0" alt="Null" class="top" z-  index:2>
            </a>
```

Comment: hey dude sorry but what do i change the class to in the

Comment: <a href="teams.html#myDiv" target="_blank">
              <img src="icon1.jpg" style='width:50%;' border="0" alt="Null" class="top" z-index:2>
            </a>

Comment: <a href="#myDiv" target="_blank">
 <img src="icon1.jpg" style='width:50%;' border="0" alt="Null" class="top" z-  index:2>
            </a>

Comment: it did it for the teams one that is top left but not for the rest thanks for your help